# Allow Apache to run composer update dependencies in a web application

Tags: php, apache, symfony, composer-php

In a **LAMP application** based on `Symfony2`, I need to provide a specific **web service in admin panel to update "on-demand" specific dependencies managed by `Composer`** ( ~like plugins update in `WordPress` admin panel).

Application are deployed on servers by real user (application files owner are not `www-data`).

I thought these solutions :

1. **Apache user run directly Composer shell command** (shell_exec, Symfony/Process):

   - `composer.lock` must be writeable for Apache user
   - `$COMPOSER_HOME` path must be defined and writable for Apache user
   - All concerned vendor dependency files must be writable for Apache user
   - Apache user should be able **to use GIT client with SSH protocol**
   - ... *maybe other points i don't think*
2. **Apache user run Composer shell command as real user, using sudo**

   - `sudo` must be configured to allow apache user to execute (only) composer as specified real user ([Run a shell command as another user or change Apache's user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797816/run-a-shell-command-as-another-user-or-change-apaches-user))
   - ...
3. Use **third-party tool, cronjob or Event-driven I/O** (`ReactPHP` ?)

I'm not sure if theses solutions are good, **secure** and **simple to deploy**.

What is the best way for you ? Any suggestions/ideas are welcome !
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run composer with a PHP script in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219436/run-composer-with-a-php-script-in-browser)